# Combining HTML and Tkinter Text Input

Tags: html, windows, tkinter, python-3.5

I'm looking for some help in finding a way to construct a body of text that can be implemented within an HTML document upon users inputting their text to display in an Entry. I have figured out the following on how to execute the browser to open in a new window when clicking the button and displaying the HTML string. However, the area I am stuck on is grabbing the user input inside the wbEntry variable to function with the HTML string outputted by 'message'. I was looking at lambda's to use as a command within wbbutton, but not sure if that's the direction to look for a solution.

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def wbbrowser():
    f = open('index.html','w')
    message = "<html><head></head><body><p>This is a test</p></body</html>"
    f.write(message)
    f.close()
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('index.html')


wbGui = Tk()
source = StringVar()


wbGui.geometry('450x450+500+300')
wbGui.title('Web Browser')

wblabel = Label(wbGui,text='Type Your Text Below').pack()

wbbutton = Button(wbGui,text="Open Browser",command = wbbrowser).pack()

wbEntry = Entry(wbGui,textvariable=source).pack()
```

I am using Python 3.5 and Tkinter on a Windows 7. The code above does not operate for me on my Mac OSX as that would require a different setup for my wbbrowser function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So... you're just wanting to get what's in `wbEntry` to appear inside of the `message` string when the user clicks on the button?

Comment: Yes, thank you!! Insert variable into a string.. I should have thought about that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are associating a `StringVar` with the entry widget, all you need to do is fetch the value from the variable before inserting it into the message.

```
def wbbrowser():
    ...
    text = source.get()
    message = "<html><head></head><body><p>%s</p></body</html>" % text
    ...
```